# How To use UITextField Value of Alertview in Another Function?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield, uialertview

I have a UITextField in my Alertview. Now I want to used this UITextfield value in Another Function.
Just look my Code below.

My Alertview Code:

```
 -(void)AlertView 
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];

alert.title = @"Used Defualt Name Or you Can Save Recoring With Your Own Name";
alert.message = @"";
alert.delegate = self;
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];   
myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 82.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[alert addSubview:myTextField];
[alert show];
[alert release];

 }
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

NSLog(@"name:%@   buttonID:%d",myTextField.text,buttonIndex);
if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    btnPlay.enabled=YES;

    mySongname = myTextField.text;
     NSLog(@"song name:%@  ",mySongname);
}
else {
   btnPlay.enabled=YES;
}
}
```

I Declare the Variable mysongname as global of my class because I use it here in same where I have alertview in below function.

```
-(IBAction)playButton:(id)sender
{ 
 // mySongname=@"my fourite songs";
  NSString *fina = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mySongname];
}
```

Now in Above function mysongname show out of scope value.but when I remove the comment which I show in above function then it works fine. I don't know why it not pass the UITextfield here.

Comment: Try setting property and synthesize to mySongname, and set value using  self.mySongname = myTextField.text;

Comment: Thanks now it work when i set it according to your instruction.please post answer here so i wana to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting property and synthesize to mySongname, and set value using self.mySongname = myTextField.text;

Comment: just do as i did for you.please

Answer (score 0):

just declare a string object and set its value and use its value into alert view in the class